# VBA to copy paste excel into a powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks to BigBen - the below code is an example corrected that show how to clear slides in an existing powerpoint, and then copy paste a range from excel to powerpoint as picture. The initial error was about the cells be not defined, then working around the line to define the shape in powerpoint. The code should be working.

```
Option Explicit
    Sub ExportToPPT()

    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    Dim ppFileName As String
    ppFileName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Financial Summary.pptx"

    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(filename:=ppFileName)

    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 9
        Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(i)

        Dim j As Integer
        For j = ppSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If ppSlide.Shapes(j).Type = msoPicture Then
                ppSlide.Shapes(j).Delete
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

'preparation of the export

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long

    Workbooks("A.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Graph Data").Select
    Range("E4").Value = "8"
    Application.Calculate

   `Set Sel = Selection
Set source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("waterfall").Range("B1")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("waterfall").Range("D1:AE40").Copy

Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(9)
ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap

   End Sub
```

Comment: the variable "cell" is a range variable, so you can [Dim cell As Range] or [Dim cell As Variant]

Comment: Thanks @KacireeSoftware - however this moved to error 1004, action won't work on multiples selections on the following line `Union(Range("D1:AE" & lRow), Range(cells(1, cells.Column), cells(lRow, cells.Column))).CopyPicture`

Comment: Let me plug your code in and run it on my machine. I will be back

Comment: Looks like `Range.CopyPicture` can't be used with a `Union` of multiple selections - you might need a workaround.

Comment: I see your point - is there an alternative in code that could select directly a range from "D1:AE40" and avoid then the Union ?

Comment: @BigBen I concur.

Comment: Can you explain what range needs to be copied, or maybe add a sample screenshot?

Comment: I need to capture all the contents from cell D1:AE40 from the worksheet "B" in the example and paste it as a picture in the slide number 9.

Comment: What are `lCol` and `lRow` equal to in this case - are you trying to find the last row/column within `D1:AE40`?

Comment: correct - I thought to define the selection D1:AE40 to reflect it as a Lcol and Lrow for the shape but maybe I over complicated it

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't sound like you need `Union` at all.

Comment: I get an object required when I removed the union and code instead the following `For Each cell In Range("D1:AE40").CopyPicture`

Comment: I was able to fix the code myself based on your comments - I will upload the correction in the above code for future reference if anyone has the same question - thanks all for your help @BigBen ;-)